# Reduce Space Between Characters in New Command

Tags: macros, spacing, typography

I'm not satisfied with the new command I've made. My code:

```
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\mbox{P}_{#1}\left(#2\right)}
$\ps{Y}{y}$ %example
```

My problem is that there's too much space between the subscripted Y and the left parenthesis. Does anyone know how to get these two closer together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `\left`-`\right` subformula is treated as an Inner atom and this adds some space before and after the subformula, in certain circumstances. One can get the desired behavior by

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\operatorname{P}_{#1}
  \mathopen{}\left(#2\right)\mathclose{}}
```

so the spacing inserted will disappear (TeX doesn't insert space between an opening atom and an inner one, nor between an inner atom and a closing one).

It's better to define "P" with `\operatorname` than with `\mbox`.

As Philippe Goutet remarks, if superscripts or subscripts need to be attached to the closing parenthesis, the definition should be

```
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\operatorname{P}_{#1}
  \mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(#2\right)}}
```

Comment: And if you want something like `$\ps{X}{\dfrac{1}{y}}^2$` to work correctly (the exponent `2` will be too low with your solution), you can by using `\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(#2\right)}`.

Comment: @Philippe You can use `\ps{X}{\dfrac{1}{y}\aftergroup^\aftergroup2}` `:)`

Comment: if you like `\aftergroup` trickery, you can use it to redefine `\left` and `\right` to produce open and close atoms (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right). Here, it's really a shame that your macro `\ps` doesn't work correctly if there's an exponent afterwards when the fix is so simple.

Comment: @Philippe I don't think that the OP has the necessity to set exponents after the parenthesis. But I'll edit my answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I knew posting to StackExchange.com was the right thing to do. I really appreciate all of the help. I'm definitely coming back here with any future questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a math kerning with a negative value (change `-3mu` to the value that best suits your needs):

```
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\mbox{P}_{#1}\mkern-3mu\left(#2\right)}
```

Comment: this will leave an unwanted space *after* the construction. Moreover it won't work in subscripts and superscripts (this would be solved with `\nonscript\mskip-3mu`, though).

Comment: @Max: as @egreg has pointed out, my solution is not completely correct. You should accept egreg's answer instead of mine.

Comment: I remembered a message by Will Robertson on `comp.text.tex`; he ascribed the method to F. Mittelbach.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how negative spacing commands are used on [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Controlling_horizontal_spacing). So for your example, it would be something like

```
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\mbox{P}_{#1}\!\left(#2\right)}
```

Comment: We prefer for answers on this site to be self contained rather than just links to other pages. Could you perhaps add to this answer some examples of how the OP might achieve the desired results?

Comment: @ Seamus: Uhm, I did actually put an example but maybe I am missing the point, care to correct me please?