# Spacing too large with exponents and big Oh

Tags: math-mode, kerning

What's the correct way to typeset the following to get the normal spacing you would expect were you to, for example, write the terms out by hand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \prod_{i=1}^m X_i \right)^n \]
\[ O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \]
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

In the first case the space to the exponent 'n' is too large. In the latter case the space between the 'O' and the open bracket is too large.

Comment: I don't think the spacing looks that bad actually... You could manually adjust the spacing by adding a negative hspace. `\[ O\hspace*{-.25em}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \]` and the same for the exponent.

Comment: Regarding the space between the 'O' and the '(', this is discussed at great length in [Spacing around \left and \right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways to address spacing issues. In the first example you give, reproduced in the first `gather*` line in the code below, both the right large parenthesis and the exponent `n` indeed seem to be spaced too loosely.

Inserting a "negative thinspace", `\!`, before each of these two items (line 2) does eliminate the earlier looseness. Unfortunately, the overall expression now looks a bit cramped. In my view, the *real culprits* for making the expression in line 1 look unsatisfactory are (i) the near-collision between the opening (left) parenthesis and the subscript term below the product symbol and (ii) parentheses that are *too tall* relative to what they contain; see pp. 148-9 of the TeXbook for an explanation of this second point. In line 3 below, I therefore (a) insert a *positive* thinspace, `\,` after the opening parenthesis and (b) use `\biggl` and `\biggr` parentheses, as they are slightly smaller (and also a tiny bit less wide!) than those produced by `\left(` and `\right)`. I think the result now looks both balanced and neither too loose nor too tight. :-)

The second example you provide is affected by the automatic additional spacing that's inserted when TeX creates `\left`- and `\right` parentheses. Switching to `\biggl` and `\biggr` parentheses, as in line 4 below, eliminates this excess space. If you do *not* wish to give up the convenience of automatic sizing of parentheses generated by `\left`-`\right` pairs, you could instead insert a negative thinspace, `\!`, between the `O` and the `\left(`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin {gather*}
\intertext{Original}
 \left( \prod_{i=1}^m X_i \right)^n  \\       %% "line 1"
\intertext{less space on \emph{right}:}
 \left( \prod_{i=1}^m X_i \!\right)^{\!n} \\  %% "line 2"
\intertext{more space on \emph{left}, biggl-biggr parens:}
 \biggl(\,\prod_{i=1}^m X_i\biggr)^n \\       %% "line 3"
\intertext{Left-right vs.\ biggl-biggr parentheses}
 O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \qquad O\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)  %% "line 4"
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted. However the O{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} answer below is surprising, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 6):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \prod_{i=1}^m X_i \right)^{\mkern-5mu n} \]
\[ O{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} \]
\end{document}
```

with `{...}` you do not get the delimiterspace. The exponent is correct but you can use `\mkern` to get it nearer to the parenthesis

Comment: @Herbet, That's really great, thanks. I have to ask, where is the {...} feature that you then don't get the delimiterspace documented?

Comment: @Raphael Clifford: in the TeXbook, everything in math in `{...}` is like a so called math atom. See also http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf