# Is there a way to improve kerning on mathematics?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, kerning

It seems that some mathematical formulae do not have as good kerning as standard text? Taking a specific example, I would like to change

[image]

The version on the left is LaTeX produced from `\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^{\frac{8}{3}}`, whereas the version on the right is a mock-up created in MS Paint.

Comment: For individual cases you can add some `\!` before the fraction.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31313/10499

Comment: @percusse If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual negative space commands such as `\!` (See [Large negative spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces) )from the math-mode can be put before the exponent to shift it to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^{\frac{8}{3}}
\]
\[
\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^{\!\frac{8}{3}}
\]
\[
\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^{\!\!\frac{8}{3}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]