# What does \right. do?

Tags: math-mode

I have tried searching for `\right.` in many places but have not been able to decipher its magical properties. Many texts use the arcane symbol but none that I have found explain it. The composition of the symbol with its elusive period, has also made the search problematic.

Please help!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It produces an "invisible" delimiter that is used to match a corresponding `\left`. You can use it when you need a delimiter only on one side of the expression. [`lshort`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort) also describes it.

An example of such usage would be typesetting a multi-case function definition: with a figure brace on the left and nothing on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

\[
  |x| = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
       x, & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
      -x, & \text{otherwise} 
    \end{array} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(NOTE: This is only an example and has improper spacing. In real life you would use the `cases` environment for this.)

Comment: As a true real-life example, I've used it for integration bounds. Something like `\[ \int_a^b f(x) = \left. F(x) \right |_{x=a}^{x=b} \]`.

Comment: @root45: I used to do that, but I found that the bar is not long enough when `F(x)` is of normal height.  It turned out to be better just to use `\Bigr|` in that situation.

Answer (score 32):

`\right.` is not exactly an *invisible delimiter*, because it inserts a small space, which is usually desirable, but *no symbol* and so can be used to pair a `\left`. Similarly, also `\left.` will insert a small space.

The space inserted has width `\nulldelimiterspace`; the default value is 1.2pt, so it's small but noticeable. In some cases one doesn't desire such a space and it's necessary to eliminate it. However it should be kept in mind that TeX processes a formula, inserting kerns and penalties only when it has scanned the "end-of-formula" marker (`$` or `$$`, the latter usually masked by macros in LaTeX) and uses the values of the parameters which are valid *at that moment*.

How can one define a "really void" delimiter that matches a `\left` or `\right` without adding spaces? Here's how:

```
\newcommand{\zerodel}{.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

Now

```
\[ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right\zerodel \]
```

won't add the small space after the formula. One can think to better examples. Here's code that shows the differences (the parameter `\nulldelimiterspace` has been set to 10pt for better showing the result, the `\bigg|` is to make the delimiter grow and `|` indicates the end of the space taken by the "invisible delimiter"):

```
$\left(\bigg|\right.|$

$\left(\bigg|\right.|\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$ 

$\left(\bigg|\right\zerodel|$

$|\left.\bigg|\right)$

$|\left.\bigg|\right)\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$

$|\left\zerodel\bigg|\right)$
```

[image]

Comment: @user0 `\mright.` removes the additional space due to the inner atom, but inserts `\nulldelimiterspace`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `\left<char>` and `\right<char>` you can create delimiters which are resized to be as high as the content between them. So e.g. `\left(` ... `\right)` creates big `( ... )`. These build a pair and you can't just use `\left` without `\right`. However, it is possible to use different characters for both.

Now, if you want a resizable delimiter on the left side but not on the right side you can use the dot `.` with `\right` to use it but tell him to not print anything there. A good example would be some case statement: `a = \left\{ <some cases> \right.`

Answer (score 5):

a `\left` needs a `right` and vice versa.
With `\left.`or `\right.` TeX inserts a `\nulldelimiterspace` which is by default 1.2pt