# Space added after \right

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, delimiters

I have a problem regarding the space added by `\right.`.

I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34908/14836) answer regarding the topic, where @egreg proposes a macro that deletes this space. However, when using this in my own documents the space is still added. I have written a MWE where I set the value of `\nulldelimiterspace` to `10pt` for clarity. The MWE is:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\zerodel}{.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{10pt}

I$\left(\delta t;\delta t;\right.\delta t;\delta t$I

I$\left(\delta t;\delta t;\right\zerodel\delta t;\delta t$I

I$\left(\delta t;\delta t;\delta t;\delta t\right.$I

I$(\delta t;\delta t;\delta t;\delta t$I

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Result]

You can clearly see the large 10pt space after the second semicolon (line 1), a smaller space (line 2) where the `\zerodel` was used, a space *after* the math (line 3) where `\right.` was moved after the math block and no space added at all where neither `\left` nor `\right` where used (line 4).

The look of line 4 is what I want, but I want to have the `\left`/`\right` autospacing.

Why is `\zerodel` not working and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Put the semicolon *after* `\right\zerodel`, or it won't act as punctuation. However, the "inner" atom built by `\left` and `\right` still will give an additional space. Use instead `\mleft` and `\mright` from the `mleftright` package.

Comment: Adding `mleftright` fixed the problem. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.  Is there any reason for using `\zerodel` when using `mleftright` at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at some variations, keeping out `\right.` until the last. We'll use the `mleftright` package by H. Oberdiek.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\newcommand{\zerodel}{.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{10pt} % just for experiment

I$\left(\delta t;\delta t\right\zerodel;\delta t;\delta t$I

I$\mleft(\delta t;\delta t\mright\zerodel;\delta t;\delta t$I

I$(\delta t;\delta t;\delta t;\delta t$I

I$\mleft(\delta t;\delta t\mright.;\delta t;\delta t$I

\end{document}
```

[image]

### First line.

A space is inserted between `\right\zerodel` and `;` because a subformula between `\left` and `\right` makes for an "inner" atom.

### Second and third line

The result is exactly the same. Notice that the semicolon has to go after `\mright\zerodel`, because otherwise its "punctuation atom" character would be hidden in the subformula.

### Fourth line

With `\mleft.` the `\nulldelimiterspace` kern is inserted anyway. The pair `\mleft`–`\mright` just removes the "inner" character to the subformula.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the usage of `\zerodel`!

Comment: Is there any reason why one shouldn't set `\nulldelimiterspace` to zero?

Comment: @elemakil It's thought for balancing the other delimiter's width.

Answer (score 2):

neither latex nor `amsmath` is needed for this.  it's basic tex behavior.

try this with tex, not latex:

```
I$\left(\delta t;\delta t;\right.\delta t;\delta t$I
\bye
```

here's the result:

[image: output of example code]

(i know this isn't an answer, but output can't be shown in a comment.)

in `plain.tex`, knuth adjusts the space after the nondirectional `\big`, `\Big`, etc., commands like this:

```
\def\big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to8.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
\def\n@space{\nulldelimiterspace\z@ \m@th}
```

curiously, if the equivalent of `\n@space` is inserted after `\right.` the space is decreased by about half, but it doesn't disappear entirely.  so an expedition into appendix g or tex itself seems to be required.  (but not for me today.)

however, this is yet another good reason not to blindly use `\left` and `\right` with all delimiters.