# Equation: Using \left brackets inserts unwanted space

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right)

I'm having some problems with writing down an equation in LaTeX. It's only a minor issue regarding appearance, but I'm kind of a perfectionist. And isn't that why we use LaTeX anyway?

Consider the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\exp[-\frac{x}{2}]
\end{equation}
```

The brackets following the exponential indicator `\exp` are closely placed next to "exp", clearly indicating that it's the variables for the exponential function. However, since the argument of the exponential function contains a fraction, it's appropriate to resize the brackets. So I let the brackets be resized automatically according to:

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\exp\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right]
\end{equation}
```

Indeed, the brackets are now automatically appropriately sized. However, for some reason, extra white space appears between "exp" and the first "[" bracket. It now looks like the function "exp" and the term in brackets are two independent components.

I haven't found a way to solve this issue. I'm quite surprised that a system like LaTeX, known for its excellent equation capabilities, exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Spacing around \left and \right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/5764). Please see whether this modification (as a general solution) solves your problem and report back via adding a comment. There are other on-the-fly alternatives, like using `\!` on the outside which inserts a negative `\thinspace` to reduce the white space left by the `\left` and `\right` delimiter pair.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some of the possibilities, using the proposed solution of [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/5764)  and adding `\!` (a negative `\thinspace`):

[image: Spacing around left/right operators]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \exp[-\tfrac{x}{2}] \\
  f(x) &= \exp\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right] \\
  f(x) &= \exp\!\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right]
\end{align*}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \exp[-\tfrac{x}{2}] \\
  f(x) &= \exp\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right] \\
  f(x) &= \exp\!\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In both examples, the first equation represents the regular delimiters, second show the traditional `\left` and  `\right` pair, while the third shows the addition of a negative `\thinspace` using `\!`.

Answer (score 3):

if you want the same spacing use

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\exp\kern\nulldelimiterspace[-\dfrac{x}{2}] 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: The space between `\exp` and `\left[` is not `\nulldelimiterspace` but a thin space because `\exp` is `\mathop` and `\left` is `\mathinner`.

Comment: I didn't said that! I said that that helps in this case ..

Comment: What you said is "if you want the same spacing", which is not what `\nulldelimiterspace` will give (with the standard value, it will be close, but as both `\nulldelimiterspace` and the thin space can be changed, there's no guarantee on that always being true).

Comment: everything can be changed ... ;-)

Comment: ... but some things remain equal. Loading some math font packages (like fourier) will change the thin space. It's rarer, but some commands do set `\nulldelimiterspace` to 0pt in their argument (the only example I know is mathtool's `\cramped`).

Comment: if commands set lengths locally to 0 is not of interest here!

Comment: Not quite true, as you could want to write `$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cramped{\exp\kern\nulldelimiterspace[-\frac{x}{2}]}}$` and get the same result as with `$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cramped{\exp\left[-\frac{x}{2}\right]}}$`, which will not be the case.

Comment: I know all that! And I also know when using `\nulldelimterspace` and when not!

Comment: Sorry for having bothered you, then. I only wanted to try to understand why you suggested using `\nulldelimiterspace` here even though it has absolutely nothing to do with the problem. It isn't really important anyway, since it's the contrary which must be done: suppress the space between `\exp` and `\left[` instead of adding it between `\exp` and a normal `[`.