# Spacing around longer function argument's parentheses

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The line

```
i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \hat{\imath}(\xi(z),t)
```

[image]

produces (for my eyes, at least) too little space between the successive function calls. It is difficult to visually distinguish the three calls. I guess the underlying reason is that the expressions that serve as function arguments are relatively long. For comparison,

```
i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x) \delta(y) \hat{\imath}(\xi(z),t)
```

[image]

already looks a lot better in my opinion.

I know that I could

1. Manually adjust spacing using `\,` etc., including the option to define a macro that does this automatically.
2. Insert `\cdot` as a means of adding seperating space.

However, my question is: Is there a canonical way (e.g. a package) of dealing with this problem? I imagine I'm not the first one to encounter this problem... still, I wasn't able to find useful, general solutions to the problem.

A possible solution might be something along the lines of

```
i(x,y,t) = \delta \funcargs{x-\ell_x(z)} \delta \funcargs{y-\ell_y(z)} \hat{\imath} \funcargs{\xi(z)}{t}
```

Note that I find the use of `\cdot` to be unsatisfying since it introduces inconsistency in the document (sometimes having the dot and sometimes not, with the meaning being the same).

Comment: Use `\,` or `\;` to add more space.

Comment: As I said, I know that I can manually adjust spacing. This is not the solution I was asking for. I'll try to further clarify the question.

Comment: How do you feel about wrapping them inside `\mathinner{...}`s?

Comment: Because the added space is dependent on what follows (another function[yes] vs. a comma or an additional close paren [no]), making it active would seem to be the only way.  And making it active would introduce all sorts of other problems, I would guess.  Thus, I agree with @skpblack that adding it manually is the best approach.

Comment: @Steven: With `\mathinner`, no space would be inserted between it and `\mathclose`, but `\thinmuskip` would be inserted between it and `\mathpunct`.

Comment: @morbusg I see. Very nice.  (but `\,` still seems simpler)

Comment: @morbusg I don't know about `\mathinner`. Thanks for the hint, going to research that right now.

Comment: @morbusg `\mathinner` does exactly what I want! If you add a short answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No package can distinguish `)` as function argument delimiter if you don't mark it in some way. My preferred way for avoiding ambiguities (if any) would be `\cdot`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let me give a paraphrasing from The TeXbook showing the amounts of spaces between different types of math atoms:

[image]

where

- `Ord` includes things like `a`, `\theta`, and things inside `\mathord` or just plain `{}`'s;
- `Op` includes things like `\sin`, `\gcd`, and things inside `\mathop`;
- `Bin` includes things like `\pm`, `\otimes`, and things inside `\mathbin`;
- `Rel` includes things like `\leq`, `\mid`, and things inside `\mathrel`;
- `Open` includes things like `\langle`, `(`, and things inside `\mathopen`;
- `Close` includes things like `\rangle`, `)`, and things inside `\mathclose`;
- `Punct` includes things like `,`, `.`, and things inside `\mathpunct`;
- `Inner` includes things like `\cdots` and things inside `\mathinner`.

Here is an example [plain-tex](/questions/tagged/plain-tex) document illustrating a couple of different ways:

```
\let\funarg\mathinner
\def\funop#1{\mathop{{}#1}}
$$ i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \hat\imath(\xi(z),t), $$
$$ i\funarg{x,y,z,t} = \delta\funarg{(x-\ell_x(z))} \delta\funarg{(y-\ell_y(z))} \hat\imath\funarg{(\xi(z),t)}, $$
$$ \funarg{i(x,y,z,t)} = \funarg{\delta(x-\ell_x(z))} \funarg{\delta(y-\ell_y(z))} \funarg{\hat\imath(\xi(z),t)}, $$
$$ \funop i(x,y,z,t) = \funop\delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \funop\delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \funop{\hat\imath}(\xi(z),t), $$
\bye
```

[image]

So as you can see, you probably want the last option of using a `\mathop` atom for the function "name".

With LaTeX, this could be defined as follows (the second row below shows the output of your original code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\funop[1]{\mathop{{}#1}}
\begin{document}
$i(x,y,z,t) = \funop\delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \funop\delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \funop{\hat\imath}(\xi(z),t)$

vs.

$i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \hat{\imath}(\xi(z),t)$
\end{document}
```

(The reason I didn't include the parenthesis in the command is that I felt it would be too much effort to measure the arguments to decide on the size of the fences. I think it's simpler to just manually define the height with `\bigl(` etc., and also it's nicer to see the parens in the manuscript instead of `{}`'s)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! What I do right now is `\newcommand{\func}[2]{\operatorname{#1} \left( #2 \right)}`. I first tried `\mathop` as it seemed more appropriate than `\mathinner` but it resulted in weird vertival spacing, so I settled to `\operatorname`. I have `\left` and `\right` fixed as proposed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610/64293. The result looks really good in my opinion.

Comment: @jhin: Yes, the first empty group in my plain-tex definition takes care of the weird vertical spacing. I could have sworn there is either a LaTeX or AMSMath command to achieve the same thing, I'm just having trouble finding it.

Comment: @jhin You can use `\mleft` and `\mright` from `mleftright` package. In any case, I wouldn't use them. I would prefer a wrapper around `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parenthesis{\lparen}{\rparen}` and then passing the optional comand like `\func[\big]{..}{..}` to `\parenthesis[\big]{..}`.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks! Though, I was thinking of a `\mathop` to be the "suggested" math atom because the `\mathinner` adds a `\thinmuskip` in case of a following `\mathpunct` atom. Do you recall if there is a LaTeX or AMSMath command which basically does `\mathop{{}#1}`?

Comment: @Manuel - and could you elaborate a bit on why you would prefer such a wrapper over the `\mleftright`package...?

Comment: @jhin `\mleft` and `\mright` are already “fixed” as in the answer you linked. In any case, better than using those automatic `\left`/`\right` which doesn't always choose the best option, I would prefer a wrapper around  that delimiters which in general are recommended instead of `\left`/`\right`.

Comment: @Mico - I'm confused: Why adding the extra Latex commands? I'm completely new to this distinction (Latex vs. plain-tex), just did a bit of read-up, but to me it seems that `\mathop{{}#1}` works in standard Latex aswell? (As should all plain-tex commands, if I get it right...?) Actually it is what I'm using right now (due to vertical alignment issues with `\operatorname`).

Comment: @jhin - For the example at hand, both approaches work. The "LaTeX approach" is to try to keep the content and the way it's displayed separate. The big advantage of setting up a macro such as `\funop` (and then using it consistently, of course) is that it allows for a quick and easy global style should you, say, at some point in the future want to use square brackets instead of round parentheses, or size the parentheses differently, of employ a different amount of spacing. Using `\mathop` hard-codes some of these choices, making it more difficult to modify the appearance of these terms.

Comment: @Mico - We completely agree on the benefit of macros! My question was why you proposed the use of `\newcommand\funop[2]{\mathinner{#1(#2)}}` as a "with Latex" solution instead of `\newcommand\funop[2]{\mathop{{}#1}(#2)}` as originally proposed by @morbusg ?

Comment: @jhin: I think I'm to blame here as I'm the one who brought up the `\mathinner`. Anyhow, let me change that into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Inserting a thinspace (`\,`) between the multiplicative factors should work. Inserting `\cdot` in these locations should work too. You could also combine the thinspaces with making the outer parentheses a tad bigger than the inner ones (by using `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`). The three possibilities are illustrated below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \, \delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \, \hat{\imath}(\xi(z),t)$

$i(x,y,z,t) = \delta(x-\ell_x(z)) \cdot \delta(y-\ell_y(z)) \cdot \hat{\imath}(\xi(z),t)$

$i(x,y,z,t) = \delta\bigl(x-\ell_x(z)\bigr) \, \delta\bigl(y-\ell_y(z)\bigr) \, 
    \hat{\imath}\bigl(\xi(z),t)\bigr)$
\end{document}
```

One can automate the third method by creating a macro such as

```
\def\myfunc#1{\bigl(#1\bigr)\,}
```

and then typing

```
$i(x,y,z,t) = \delta\myfunc{x-\ell_x(z)} \delta\myfunc{y-\ell_y(z)} 
    \hat{\imath}\myfunc{\xi(z),t)}$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I prefer the solution given by morbusg, though. Note that `\bigl` etc. introduce additional (undesired) spacing between the function name and the parentheses, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40829/equation-using-left-brackets-inserts-unwanted-space

Comment: @jhin - You may have misinterpreted that posting: The extra, unwanted space is inserted if one uses `\left(` and `\right)`. In contrast, *no extra space* is inserted by `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`. You can verify this assertion by modifying the third row of the code above to omit the two `\,` directives : You'll find that there's no absolutely no extra space.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the two produce the same spacing, so I looked at your attached picture and concluded that *yes* they do, since in fact there is a larger space between the delta and the parenthesis in the third row than in the two previous rows... might just be the effect of the scaling, though. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @jhin - The additional whitespace in the third row comes from the `\,` macros, *not* from `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`. It's exactly the same amount of whitespace as in the first row (which also uses `\,` macros).

Comment: Sorry, perhaps should have clarified: I'm really referring to the whitespace between the `\delta` and its successive `(` or `\bigl`, respectively. And that is indeed a tiny little bit larger in the third row than in the two previous rows.

Comment: @jhin That's a mix of the glyph design and the viewer Mico was using. The glyph itself has more space, but the viewer clearly shows it as extreme.

Comment: @jhin - Thanks. For me, the main advantage of using different sizes for the inner and outer parentheses is a modest improvement in the legibility/parsability of the entire formula. Obviously, if you think that your formulas are readable enough when all parentheses have exactly the same size, there would be no point in making the sizes vary.