# Horizontal spacing for function arguments in fractions

Tags: math-mode, spacing, fractions

I'm writing with collegues on a document that heavily uses one kind of custom operator (here: a probability density function). We have not decided finally what symbols to use. Consequently, we use a custom operator definition

```
% probability density
\newcommand{\pdensity}[1]{p\!\del{#1}}%
```

where `\del` is the brace-wrapping command from package `commath`. The negative thinspace `\!` is needed in my opinion to distinguish argument braces from other ocurring braces, which have a bit more seperation.

In contrast to @morbusg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210337/53868) my opinion is to collect the braces in the command definition; This has proven handy to me when working with operators like expectation, where co-authors later decided to switch from brackets to braces.

Further I absolutely need automatic sizing for the argument braces, thus the use of `\del` (an other possible alternative wolud have been `\left(` and `\right)`, which I am positive `commath uses internally`).

So far this works for me in `displaymath` environments as well as in `inlinemath`. But strange things occur when using fractions (as required in bayesian inference).

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/commath/commath.pdf
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% probability density
\newcommand{\pdensity}[1]{p\!\del{#1}}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \int \left[ \frac{\pdensity{x^{(i)} }}{\pdensity{x^{(i)} }} \right] \dif x
        &&
        \frac{ \frac{\pdensity{a}}{\pdensity{b}}}{x + y}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Suddenly the brace sizing varies (problem 1) (in denominator and numerator), and I have no clue as to why. Further, the negative thinspace is too much, effectively printing operatorname and brace through each other (problem 2). Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

For problem 2, this might possibly be solved by seperating cases in the command definition for `\pdensity`, but I have no clue at what properties to look.

Problem 1 ie even more strange, I'd like to hear any speculations on how to fix this.

Comment: Don't use `commath`. All macros it defines are wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't ask why the parentheses in the first fraction are smaller, but why they're too big in the numerator. Besides, also the brackets are way too large.

Comment: @egreg : Okay, I get that I should not use `commath` in the first place. But replacing `\del` with  `\left(` and `\right)` still yields the same strange results. So to refine my question: why is the automatic sizing not working correctly? The inner term is exactly the same in numerator and denominator.

Comment: Okay, I got it working correctly. Based on a misunderstanding on my part, I just stopped using the `\del command`, but when actually not loading the package `commath` the 'amsmath' autosizing works correctly again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `commath`. Its macros are full of bugs.

You get better result with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`, which allows full control over the size of the fences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
\newcommand{\pdensity}{p\paren}

\begin{document}

\[
\int\biggl[\frac{ \pdensity{x^{(i)}} }{ \pdensity{x^{(i)}} }\biggr]\,dx
\qquad
\int\biggl[\frac{ \pdensity[\big]{x^{(i)}} }{ \pdensity[\big]{x^{(i)}} }\biggr]\,dx
\qquad
\frac{ \frac{\pdensity{a}}{\pdensity{b}}}{x + y}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that there's no need to have large fences; my preference would go to the first of the two formulas with the integral. It is as readable and less obtrusive than the second one.

[image]

You can do

```
\pdensity{x}
\pdensity[\big]{x}
\pdensity[\Big]{x}
\pdensity[\bigg]{x}
\pdensity[\Bigg]{x}
\pdensity*{x}
```

The last one uses automatic sizing (use it only when really needed).

Comment: Your suggestion is indeed an acceptable workaround. Thank you for clarifying and elaborating this.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I'd suggest typesetting the differential operator with an upright font.

Comment: @Peiffap That's your personal preference. In my view, this “d” is not an operator, but it's attached to the variable as a single unit. I'm not alone in this.