# Need help re-defining the basic trig functions

Tags: macros

I'd like to define my own commands to replace `\sin`, `\cos`, `\tan`, etc... I'd like to be able to use `\tan[a]{x}` to mean `\tan^{a}{(x)}`, and `\tan{x}` to mean just `\tan{(x)}`.

I've tried modeling a solution based on something I found online for having a command with an optional parameter, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
\let\sin\oldsin

\def\sin{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{\oldsin^{#1}{(#2)}}
\def\@without#1{\oldsin{(#1)}}
```

It complains about \oldsin not being a command.

I'd also like this to be able to function in combination with another command I made:

```
\renewcommand\arcsin[1]{\sin[-1]{(#1)}}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use `amsmath` (and I recommend you do), the definition of `\sin` is

```
\renewcommand\sin{\qopname\relax o{sin}}
```

so you just need something like

```
\renewcommand\sin[1][]{\qopname\relax o{sin}%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else^{#1}\fi % test if the argument is empty
}
```

Doing this for all the functions is really annoying, so you can abstract it by

```
\newcommand{\changefunction}[1]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1][]%
    {\qopname\relax o{#1}\ifx\relax##1\relax\else^{##1}\fi}}
```

and then

```
\changefunction{sin}
\changefunction{cos}
\changefunction{tan}
```

Finally, you can do

```
\renewcommand{\arcsin}{\sin[-1]}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\changefunction}[1]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1][]%
    {\qopname\relax o{#1}\ifx\relax##1\relax\else^{##1}\fi}}
\changefunction{sin}
\changefunction{cos}
\changefunction{tan}

\renewcommand{\arcsin}{\sin[-1]}

\begin{document}
$\sin\alpha+\sin[2]\alpha\ne\arcsin(1/2)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

From a LaTeX point of view I don't think you gain anything with these definitions:

```
\sin^{2}
```

is as easy to type as `\sin[2]` and clearer.

From a mathematical point of view, I find that the notation you want to use for the arcsine is ambiguous and confusing. If the exponent "2" means "square the sine", the exponent "–1" will mean to a student "the reciprocal of the sine".

Comment: Every prof I've had makes it clear that \sin^{-1}(x)\neq\frac{1}{\sin(x)}... but that's just the ones I've had.

Comment: @agent154 Why the same notation should mean two *very* different things? People uses "arcsin" just because the other notation requires that clarification, which the students learn as one of the many oddities in math.

Comment: Well, I can understand the point, but it's a matter of preference for me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the edit; I forgot to apply the change.

Answer (score 6):

The sequence `\let\csA\csB` copies `\csB`’s definition to `\csA`, so you need to use

```
\let\oldsin\sin
```

Furthermore, the original `\sin` does not take an argument. I’d drop the latter argument in both, so you can still write `\sin\phi` to be displayed as “sin *φ*” and not “sin(*φ* )”.

If you use LaTeX you can simply do

```
\renewcommand*{\sin}[1][]{\oldsin\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi}
```

and get the same without the need to create your own auxiliary macros.

Though, of you really want the second argument, use

```
\renewcommand*{\sin}[2][]{\oldsin\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi (#2)}
```

but then you have no control over the size of the parentheses (say with a `\frac` in display mode). In this case you also need to drop the parenthesis in the definition of `\arcsin` (to avoid having double parentheses).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldsin\sin

\renewcommand*{\sin}[1][]{\oldsin\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}
$ \sin \phi $

$ \sin[2] \phi $

$ \sin (\phi + 2\pi) $

$ \sin[2] (\phi +2\pi) $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Well, the size of the parentheses can easily be solved by replacing () in the macro with `\left(` and `\right)`, couldn't it? I tested this out and it seems to work fine - unless you are referring to something I'm not testing.

Comment: @agent154 simply using `\left` and `\right` is no good idea, see »[Spacing around \left and \right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right)«

Comment: Using `\left` and `\right` when they are not really needed is a bad idea; it can lead to unexpected and bad results, *especially* with fonts other than (Computer|Latin) Modern.  Edit: ninja'd, sigh...

Comment: @agent154 Yes, but then they re-size even though they shouldn’t. Take a look at the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro from the `mathtools` package. Let me state, that my answer only addresses the basic question (`\oldsin` undefined). A general approach like that in egreg’s answer is, of course, preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with egreg that this interface doesn't actually save you any work and actually loses some clarity in the source.  Here's how I have been handling these powers of trig function.

I use the [`cool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cool) package.  It provides commands like `\Sin` and `\Cos` which automatically add parentheses of the right size.  It also provides their inverses `\ArcSin`, etc., which can be configured for either the "arc" style or the "inverse" style.  Since LaTeX only provides `\arc`-macros for sine, cosine, and tangent, though, you have to provide the others.

For powers, I wanted to be able to type `\Sin{x}^2` and see it as if I had typed `\sin^2(x)`.  So I redefined `\Sin` to look for `^` and adapt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\arccot}{\operatorname{arccot}}
\newcommand{\arcsec}{\operatorname{arcsec}}
\newcommand{\arccsc}{\operatorname{arccsc}}
\usepackage{cool}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\COOL@switch@arctrig}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\COOL@notation@ArcTrig}{inverse}}{#1}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal\COOL@notation@ArcTrig{arc}}{#2}{%
            \PackageError{cool}{Invalid ArcTrig option: can be only `arc' or `inv'}%
        }%
    }
}
\renewcommand{\ArcCot}[1]{%
    \COOL@switch@arctrig{\cot^{-1}}{\arccot}%
    \COOL@decide@paren{ArcTan}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\ArcSec}[1]{%
    \COOL@switch@arctrig{\sec^{-1}}{\arcsec}%
    \COOL@decide@paren{ArcSec}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\ArcCsc}[1]{%
    \COOL@switch@arctrig{\csc^{-1}}{\arccsc}%
    \COOL@decide@paren{ArcCsc}{#1}%
}

\let\COOL@Sin@Nopower\Sin
\let\COOL@Cos@Nopower\Cos
\let\COOL@Tan@Nopower\Tan
\let\COOL@Cot@Nopower\Cot
\let\COOL@Sec@Nopower\Sec
\let\COOL@Csc@Nopower\Csc

\def\Sin#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Sin@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Sin@Nopower{#1}}}
\def\Cos#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Cos@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Cos@Nopower{#1}}}
\def\Tan#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Tan@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Tan@Nopower{#1}}}
\def\Cot#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Cot@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Cot@Nopower{#1}}}
\def\Sec#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Sec@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Sec@Nopower{#1}}}
\def\Csc#1{\@ifnextchar^{\COOL@Csc@Power{#1}}{\COOL@Csc@Nopower{#1}}}

\def\COOL@Sin@Power#1^#2{\sin^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Sin}{#1}}
\def\COOL@Cos@Power#1^#2{\cos^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Cos}{#1}}
\def\COOL@Tan@Power#1^#2{\tan^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Tan}{#1}}
\def\COOL@Cot@Power#1^#2{\cot^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Cot}{#1}}
\def\COOL@Sec@Power#1^#2{\sec^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Sec}{#1}}
\def\COOL@Csc@Power#1^#2{\csc^{#2}\COOL@decide@paren{Csc}{#1}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\[
       \Style{ArcTrig=arc}
       \begin{aligned}
         \ArcSin{1} &= \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
         \ArcCos{1} &= 0              \\
         \ArcTan{1} &= \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
         \ArcCot{1} &= \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
         \ArcSec{1} &= 0              \\
         \ArcCsc{1} &= \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
       \end{aligned}
\]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\[
       \Style{ArcTrig=inverse}
       \begin{aligned}
         \ArcSin{1} &= \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
         \ArcCos{1} &= 0              \\
         \ArcTan{1} &= \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
         \ArcCot{1} &= \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
         \ArcSec{1} &= 0              \\
         \ArcCsc{1} &= \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
       \end{aligned}
\]
\end{minipage}
\[
\Sin{x}^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \Cos{2x}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

I guess a disadvantage is that if you type `\Sin x^2` you will get `\sin^2(x)` when you probably mean `\sin(x^2)`.  But the `cool` way is to embrace the arguments.