# unroll equation macros

Tags: macros, equations, sv-classes

I'm writing a book chapter for publication and the publisher accepts Latex.  I like to use equation macros

```
\newcommand{\funof}[1]{\ensuremath\left(#1\right)}
```

that I can then use in an equation

```
$i\funof{t}$
```

I assume the publisher is not going to want to have to deal with these macros.  Is there a way to unroll equations so that I can give the publisher the final expression with my macros substituted?

Edit:
This is a Springer-Verlag publication, so if anyone has experience with a similar issue.  Please let me know.

Comment: If you and the publisher are happy with the way the macro functions (no pun intended), I don't know why a publisher would forbid you from placing macros in your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Take a look at [Using `sed` in bash script to replace LaTeX aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17793815/914686).

Comment: The problem with sed and bash is that there is not a regular expression for matching brackets.

Comment: Discussion on nested brackets here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: Note that `\ensuremath\left(#1\right)` is wrong under several respects: `\ensuremath` takes an argument, so it should be `\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}`; but since you're using `\funof` in math mode, the `\ensuremath` is redundant. Also `\left` and `\right` add a wrong space: compare `$i(t)$` and `$i\left(t\right)$`.

Comment: Thanks for finding the issue with ensuremath.  This is a brief example, but there are times in my macros where \ensuremath is needed.  I am ok with the space between the name and the parentheses, and it looks like my equation macro can be fixed here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right.  My concern is how to unroll the equations for an arbitrary equation macro.

Comment: Why do you think the journal will not accept the macro?

Comment: @TorbjørnT, it looks like it may be a duplicate.  That question, unfortunately doesn't have an acceptable answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I haven't dealt with Springer before, and I've emailed their author support and I am awaiting an answer.  They do have restrictions on the math environments you can use, so I assume they have other restrictions as well.  They also apparently will convert the MS Word and Latex chapters they receive and convert the to XML.

Comment: Even if there is no accepted answer, there are several suggestions. And if you agree that it is a duplicate, we'll close this one.

Comment: I'm waiting to here back from Springer.  It is possible this question is not a duplicate.