# Making a space before and after a word in LaTeX

Tags: spacing

I have the following in LaTeX:

```
v_{i}=\frac{ 1}{ n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij} \right)^{m}x_{j}\hspace where\hspace n_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij}\right)^{m}
```

How can I make a space before and after `where`?

I tried `\hspace`, but seems didn't work.

Comment: Try `\quad` or `\qquad`

Comment: The `\hspace` macro takes an argument: `\hspace{<length>}`. For example: `\hspace{.5em}` or `\hspace{2cm}`. Also, you shouldn't use text in math-mode. After loading the `amsmath`/`amstext` package, you can use `\text{ where }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some standard spacing in math mode include `\quad` or `\qquad` but using `\hspace{<length>}` is possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
v_{i}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mleft(\mu_{ij} \mright)^{m}x_{j}\quad \text{where}\hspace{2em} n_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mleft(\mu_{ij}\mright)^{m}
\]
\[
v_{i}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij} \right)^{m}x_{j}\quad \text{where}\hspace{2em} n_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij}\right)^{m}
\]
\end{document}
```

The MWE above illustrates the effects of the use of `\left` and `\right`. For that, you can consider using the [`mleftright`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package by Heiko Oberdiek:

> The pack­age de­fines vari­ants `\mleft` and `\mright` of `\left` and
>   `\right`, that make the de­lim­iters act as `\math­open` and `\math­close`.
>   Th­ese com­mands ad­dress spac­ing dif­fi­cul­ties in sub­for­mu­las.

Read [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/10898)  for an interesting discussion about this.

Answer (score 6):

Rules of thumb:

- Never type text in math mode.
- Never type math in text mode.

Your code can be written in two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ v_{i}=\frac{ 1}{ n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij} \right)^{m}x_{j} \text{ where } n_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij}\right)^{m} \]
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Inline math looks like $v_{i}=\frac{ 1}{ n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij} \right)^{m}x_{j}$ where $n_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\mu_{ij}\right)^{m}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, `\left` and `\right` in that formula are wrong.

Comment: @egreg and the parentheses might be unneeded too. In this case, `\left` and `\right` only change the position of the superscript, is that that bad?

Comment: Yes, the result is poor.

Comment: @marczellm. Thanks for your reply. I'm interested in the first form. I tried it, but still not having the spaces

Comment: @Simplicity Note that the spaces are inside the `\text{ where }`, just next to the `{}`. If you need more space, do use `\quad` or even `\qquad`.

Comment: @egreg Are you suggesting the `\left` and `\right` are not necessary? Please edit my answer if necessary.