# Superscripts and subscripts in this equation

Tags: equations, typography

I have this equation:

```
g^{\mathsmaller{\left(1\right)}} \left( \tau \right) = \frac{\langle E_{\mathsmaller{s}}^{\mathsmaller{*}}\left( 0 \right) E_{\mathsmaller{s}} \left( \tau \right) \rangle}{\langle \lvert E_{\mathsmaller{s}} \rvert^{\mathsmaller{2}} \rangle}
```

which looks like this.

[image: equation]

Latex always brings out the OCD in me so I have some questions:

- Why is the first subscript `s` lower down than the 2nd one? How can I (should I?) force them to be at the same level or does latex know what its doing?
- Shouldn't the complex conjugate symbol `*` and the squared `2` be higher up?

Comment: @cslstr I know what you're doing, but that last edit actually made this question a lot less readable

Comment: For lowering the `s`, use `E_s^{\vphantom{*}}`. The lower placement of `*` and `2` is due to the fact that the superscript baseline still remains the same regardless of the use of `\mathsmaller`. What should also tickle your OCD is the excessive use of `\left`...`\right`, which causes wide (unnecessary) spaces around them.

Comment: @Werner -- that should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be fully in-line with what you're after, since the main suggestion is to drop a bunch of your manual formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  g^{\mathsmaller{\left(1\right)}} \left( \tau \right) = 
    \frac{\langle E_{\mathsmaller{s}}^{\mathsmaller{*}}\left( 0 \right) 
       E_{\mathsmaller{s}} \left( \tau \right) \rangle}
      {\langle \lvert E_{\mathsmaller{s}} \rvert^{\mathsmaller{2}} \rangle}
\]

\[
  g^{(1)}(\tau) = 
    \frac{\langle E_s^*(0) E_s^{\vphantom{*}}(\tau)\rangle}
         {\langle \lvert E_s \rvert^2 \rangle}
\]
\end{document}
```

I've removed the `\mathsmaller` font adjustment, as well as the over-use of `\left`...`\right` constructions. Their use typically introduces [additional/unwanted space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/5764).

Specific to your points:

- To correct for the placement of the mis-aligned `s`, insert a non-existent `*` using `E_s^{\vphantom{*}}`
- `\mathsmaller` only reduces the font size (from `\scriptstyle` to `\scriptscriptstyle` in your case), but doesn't change the baseline. As such, it seems like the superscripts can be a little higher. If you use the regular (`\scriptstyle`) superscripts, they are appropriately aligned with the top of the superscripted base.

Ps. Final OCD-ance: Perhaps you could add a small space `\,` between the operands in the fraction numerator to distinguish them properly, leaving to this output:

[image]

Comment: `E^{}_s` is sufficient, since the asterisk is not unusually big. The `\,` is wrong.

Comment: @Werner thank you very  much. I am trying to be consistent using \left( \right) or (). I see in this case it definitely is better without it so it seems to be a case by case scenario. The only thing for me is a superscript normal sized `{2}` always looks too big in my eyes but maybe I will need to learn to accept it. Either way your final equation looks much MUCH better than my first.