# Spacing between superscript and left parenthesis

Tags: spacing, superscripts

I'm wondering why Latex adds an extra space between a superscript and the left parenthesis as in this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}
\begin{document}
  $\mathscr{P}^{N}\left(\mathscr{K}\right)$
\end{document}
```

The formula is showed with an unwanted space between the superscript N and the left parenthesis. I've tried the solution drafted in [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right) , however it doesn't work in this case. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Don't use `\left(` and `\right)` unless it's really necessary. In this case, it's not, so just use `\mathscr{P}^N(\mathscr{K})`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick replies. @Adam, hope now it's fine.

Comment: @Werner, same happens without \left command...

Comment: @guillermo: The following each show different spacing: `$P^N\left(K\right)$ $P^N\bigl(K\bigr)$ $P^N(K)$`

Comment: @Werner: They look all the same to me. Just a little difference on the size of the parenthesis of option 2 (the one using the \bigl command)

Comment: @guillermo: They [may look the same, but they're not](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ooWKs.png) in terms of the spacing between the superscript and `(`. You *can* bring them closer using `\!` (yielding the fourth entry in the image link).

Comment: @Werner: Fantastic! The \! command works fine to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The definition of \left\right looks very brave to me, many constructs will expect these not to expand.

Comment: Instead of that redefinition you might try the `mleftright` package; however, I'd simply prefer using `\left` and `\right` only when really necessary. For example, in `$\mathscr{P}^{N}\left(\mathscr{K}\right)$` they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been noted in some of the comments, don't use `\left` and `\right` indiscrimately.

- If you do *not* want the extra spacing around the automatically sized parentheses but, for some reason, want automatically sized parentheses, load the `mleftright` package and use `\mleft` and `\mright`. (A direct redefinition of `\left` and `\right` of the type you're envisioning can lead to very odd results...)
- For the example at hand, automatic sizing isn't required to begin with. Observe that the size of the parentheses produced by `\left(`, `\mleft(`, and `(` are all the same. Why clutter up the code unnecessarily?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   % for \mathscr macro
\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
$\mathscr{P}^{N}\left(\mathscr{K}\right)$
$\mathscr{P}^{N}\mleft(\mathscr{K}\mright)$
$\mathscr{P}^{N}(\mathscr{K})$

\medskip
$\mathcal{P}^{N}\left(\mathcal{K}\right)$
$\mathcal{P}^{N}\mleft(\mathcal{K}\mright)$
$\mathcal{P}^{N}(\mathcal{K})$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with parentheses following the superscripted symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}

\begin{document}

$P^{N}\!\originalleft(K\originalright)$

$P^{N}\left(K\right)$

$P^{N}(K)$

$P^{N}K$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\!` in the first case is for removing the thin space normally inserted by `\left`. As you can clearly see, the spacing is exactly the same in all four cases. It depends on the `\scriptspace` feature: after a subscripted or superscripted symbol, TeX adds horizontal space in the amount of `\scriptspace`, default 0.5pt.

If you also consider that math letters are slanted and the left parenthesis has a “hole” in the left upper corner, the space appears to be bigger than it really is. But there are very good reasons for this.

You can have a fairer comparison by using upright characters and, for the superscript, something that has no sidebearings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\thinbar}{{\vphantom{|}\vrule width .2pt}}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{I}^{\thinbar}\thinbar\mathrm{I}$ $\mathrm{I}^{\mathrm{I}}\mathrm{I}$

\setlength{\scriptspace}{0pt}

$\mathrm{I}^{\thinbar}\thinbar\mathrm{I}$ $\mathrm{I}^{\mathrm{I}}\mathrm{I}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the left column you clearly see the effect of `\scriptspace`; in the right column you can compare the effect with “real” superscripts. The purpose of `\scriptspace` is exactly that of slightly detaching symbols for better reading.

### Important note

I left your redefinition of `\left` and `\right`, but I can't recommend it in any way. There's already a package doing it much better, `mleftright`.

Comment: @Mico It's not *mine*, I just left the OP's one (which I don't recommend, by the way). I added a final note.