# How to reduce vertical space between two line in IEEEeqnarray?

Tags: spacing, ieeetran

How can I lift the second line higher so that there is not a large space between the first line and the second line?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator[lr]{...}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{trantools} % for \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}...

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{
\frac12\;
\smashoperator{
\sum_{
\begin{matrix} k+l=p \\ \sigma\equiv(p,q)\text{-shuffles} \end{matrix}
     }
              }
\;\pm\left[
U_k(\gamma_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k)}),
U_l(\gamma_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k+l)})
\right]
                           }
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad
+\sum_{i<j}U_{p-1}
\left(
[\gamma_i,\gamma_j],\gamma_1,\dots,\widehat{\gamma_i},\dots,\widehat{\gamma_j},\dots,\gamma_p]
\right)
\\
&\qquad\qquad = [d,U_p] \left( \gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_p \right)
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `\smash` the whole of the first line and then open up with e.g. `\\[1ex]` at the end.  In this case it is only the depth of the expression that you want to hide so probably it is most appropriate to use `\smash[b]`.  This leaves the height intact, so spacing to the previous text is unaffected.  If you want to reduce that space too then use `\smash` instead of `\smash[b]`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator[lr]{...}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} % for \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}...

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{
   \smash[b]{\frac12\;
   \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{k+l=p \\ \sigma\equiv(p,q)\text{-shuffles}}}}
   \;\pm\left[
     U_k(\gamma_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k)}),
     U_l(\gamma_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k+l)})
   \right]
   }}
   \\[1ex]
   &\qquad\qquad\qquad
   +\sum_{i<j}U_{p-1}
   \left(
     [\gamma_i,\gamma_j],\gamma_1,\dots,\widehat{\gamma_i},\dots,
     \widehat{\gamma_j},\dots,\gamma_p]
   \right)
   \\
   &\qquad\qquad = [d,U_p] \left( \gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_p \right)
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Note on my machine the package is `IEEEtrantools`, not `trantools`.

As Mico points out the spacing after the `\pm` is too big.  This is a strange bug with spacing around `\left...\right` discussed in [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/15925)  .  One solution is to use the `mleftright` package as follows:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator[lr]{...}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} % for \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}...
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{
   \smash[b]{\frac12\;
   \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{k+l=p \\ \sigma\equiv(p,q)\text{-shuffles}}}}
   \;\pm\mleft[
     U_k(\gamma_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k)}),
     U_l(\gamma_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots,\gamma_{\sigma(k+l)})
   \mright]
   }}
   \\[1ex]
   &\qquad\qquad\qquad
   +\sum_{i<j}U_{p-1}
   \left(
     [\gamma_i,\gamma_j],\gamma_1,\dots,\widehat{\gamma_i},\dots,
     \widehat{\gamma_j},\dots,\gamma_p]
   \right)
   \\
   &\qquad\qquad = [d,U_p] \left( \gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_p \right)
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need! The IEEE somehow got lost in the process of writing the question.

Comment: Did you mean `\\[-1ex]`?

Comment: No I used `\\[1ex]` - without it the lines are too close together.  You may well prefer a smaller value, but with `\\[-1ex]` they overlap.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'd use `\smash[b]` to begin with and tell in the final note that in other cases `\smash[t]` or `\smash` could be beneficial.

Comment: The OP's code provides an interesting case illustrating why using `\left` and `\right` may not be right *even if* the size of the brackets happens to be correct: the extra space inserted to the left of `\left[` makes the `\pm` symbol like it's a binary operator. Using `\bigl[` does *not* insert extra space, and it would be clearer that `\pm` is a unary operator.

Comment: @Mico Indeed, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/15925 for workarounds

Comment: Thanks for this link. Of the workarounds mentioned in the answers, I like the `\mleft` and `\mright` macros (from Heiko's `mleftright` package) the best.

Comment: @Mico - good - now added to answer