# How to reduce space between two math environments?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

I force to use two math environments in series, this will present a big space that I don't like, I saw this [ansewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209000/how-to-reduce-vertical-space-between-two-line-in-ieeeeqnarray), he uses `\\[-1ex]` I don't want to use this method for each equation (I have a lot of equations), so is there any way to reduce the space between the two environments for the whole document?

Here is a simple example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
     f &= m a \\
     A = \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
\end{align*}  
\begin{align*}
     \frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should avoid using successive display math environments. Why not combine them into one?

Comment: this example is simple and can be combined, but I have many cases that I forced to separate the equation in two or more environment, so I asked for a solution for such case.

Comment: I can't imaging any case which force me to wrote series of successive equation which I can't merge it in one math environment (offered by `amsmath/mathtools`) . From reader side view math construct of number (different?) math environments is difficult to read and follow.

Comment: *Never* use `align` for a single equation: there's `equation` for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consecutive math displays should be avoided. If you really must group aligned display math and non-aligned content, use a single display math environment (here, `gather*`) and use an internal math environment to perform the alignment (here, `aligned`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
     r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
     f &= m a \\
     A &= \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
\end{aligned} \\
     \frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems nice.

Answer (score 5):

You can nest `align` in `gather` (not the other way around). In the example code I use numbered equations but adding the `*` will produce the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The the basic solution consists in nesting \texttt{align} in \texttt{gather}
as shown below
\begin{gather}
  \begin{align}
  r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
  f &= m a \\
  A &= \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
  \end{align}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
\end{gather}
Adding some phantoms also fixes the vertical spacing
\begin{gather}
  \begin{align}
  r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  \vphantom{\frac{1_{\mathstrut}}{2}}\\
  f &= m a               \vphantom{\frac{1_{\mathstrut}}{2}}\\
  A &= \frac{\pi}{4} d^2 \vphantom{\frac{1_{\mathstrut}}{2}}
  \end{align}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have text between the two environments, just type it in, without blank lines in between.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

If we have some word between the two environments, it's very easy:
\begin{align}
  r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
  f &= m a \\
  A &= \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
\end{align}  
where
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
\end{equation}
The important thing is not leaving blank lines before and after the math display
environments.

\end{document}
```

A blank line *can* follow a display, but only if a really new paragraph begins.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, sometimes I need to write 'where' between the two environments, I want the word has no indent, how could I do that?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool You need nothing special, I'll add the code.

Comment: Thanks, but how can it be written inside the first environment (without indent) as in your first code?

Comment: I tried this `\text{where} \\ `, but there is a lot of white space, I change the `gather` to `align` but still the same.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool I don't understand what you are trying to do; the “where” word should go where I showed.

Comment: I want exactly as in your second code, but in your first code.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool Why? I see no reason.

Comment: I add an image to the question, I want to align the above sets of equations and put some text then add another equation would also want to be aligned with above equations, this is why I want to know how to add a text between two environments?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool In that case, there's `\intertext`, see [How can I add left aligned text to an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it, but this gives you what you appear to want...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{align*}
        r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
        f &= m a \\
        A &= \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
    \end{align*}%  
\begin{align*}
        \frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{P_{(i+1,j)} - P_{(i-1,j)}}{2 \Delta\theta}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't this also remove the space before the first environment and after the last?

Comment: (1) second math environment sesms to be `gather*`, (2) as mentioned @cfr, this changes is acceptable only locally, so you need to design a group in which your changes is valid. And I agree with you, that this is not recommended solution :-).

Comment: Yes, just group them.