# How to remove the space before and after fraction line of \frac command

Tags: fractions

I find the `\frac` command add a space of 1.2 pt before and after a fraction. See the figure below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\abc{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{0}{0}}
\def\Abc{\frac00}
\def\ruleline{\rule[-6pt]{1pt}{20pt}}
\def\D{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

$\D0000000000$

$\D\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc$\ruleline

$\D\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc\abc$\ruleline

$\D00000\hspace{24pt}00000$\ruleline
\end{document}
```

You could see even the `\genfrac` which hidden the fraction line also has a (double) sep space.

Could I get a \frac struction without the space (or a cumstomized space)?

As some guys like a pair of `\left&\right` without adding a bit additional space ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right?s=13%7C0.8524)), I think a binomial coefficient `\binom` should not have an invisible space.

Comment: Now it should be ok. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All fractions receive an additional horizontal space on both sides, with width `\nulldelimiterspace` (default 1.2pt) irrespective of the font size.

If you want to have fractions without this space, you can define `\zfrac` like below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\zfrac}[2]{%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \genfrac{}{}{}{}{#1}{#2}%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
}


\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}% hairline
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% no padding

\begin{document}

\fbox{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$\displaystyle\frac{0}{0}$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\fbox{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\LARGE$\displaystyle\frac{0}{0}$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\fbox{$\displaystyle\zfrac{0}{0}$}
\fbox{\LARGE$\displaystyle\zfrac{0}{0}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]