# Hanging brackets in an align environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align

I have two formulas in an `align` environment, and the second one starts with a bracket (this particular example is simplified):

```
\begin{align}
& x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
& \left[ x_\alpha(s),  x_\beta(t) \right]
\end{align}
```

The result is terrible, apparently because of the spacing before the bracket:

[image: Standard]

Since I can't put an alignment point between the brackets, I tried to put a phantom of a bracket in the beginning of the first line as follows:

```
\begin{align}
& \phantom{\left[{}\vphantom{x_\beta(t)}\right.}
  x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
& \left[ x_\alpha(s),  x_\beta(t)\right]
\end{align}
```

The result is better, but still not perfect (my trick did not work as I expected):

[image: With a phantom]

So how can I achieve the perfect alignment?

**Update.** By the "perfect alignment" I mean that the upper *x* stands straight above the lower one:

[image: Perfect]

Comment: Consider totally dropping the left right constructions and use the manual scallers, then you *can* align inside.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& \left. x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t)\right . \\
& \left[ x_\alpha(s),  x_\beta(t)\right]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Just putting a virtual bracket (`\left.`) will do the trick, because `\left.` and `\left[` should have the same spacing.

If you like the following alignment,

[image]

then, you can use the following (also pointed out by @daleif):

```
\begin{align}
& x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
& \bigl[ x_\alpha(s),x_\beta(t)\bigr]
\end{align}
```

**Update**

Aligning at the `x`'s as per the OP's request:

```
\begin{align}
       & x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
\bigl[ & x_\alpha(s),x_\beta(t) \bigr]
\end{align}
```

[image]

**Remark**

Mathematicians often prefer the outer fences being just as tall as the tallest inner object excluding the exponents. As such, I personally prefer dropping all `\left`s or `\right`s and just putting only the brackets `[` (assuming no tall objects exist) like this:

```
\begin{align}
 & x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
[& x_\alpha(s),x_\beta(t)]
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not what I meant. I made an edit to the question.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky Please see my update!

Comment: The `\bigl.\bigr.` bit in the first equation and the `\bigr.` and `\bigl.` parts in the second aren't needed.

Comment: @Mico Right, just forgot them from the previous `\left[` and `\right]`. I edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution:

```
\begin{align}
      x_\alpha(s)       & x_\alpha(t) \\
\left[x_\alpha(s)\right.&,\left.x_\beta(t) \right]
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: the "x"s aren't aligned, and worse, the spaces around the comma look wider than they should.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you have right.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this while not throwing away the `\left[` command, thank to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145341). It goes like this (perhaps my code is too complicated and can be simplified):

```
\begin{align}
& \hphantom{ \left[ \vphantom{\dfrac{ABCD}{EFGH}} \right.\kern\nulldelimiterspace }
  x_\alpha(s) x_\alpha(t) \\
& \left[ x_\alpha(s), \dfrac{ABCD}{EFGH}\right]
\end{align}
```

[image]

Although looking promising, the `mathopen` and `mathclose` commands suggested by the other answers to the question in the link above do not solve the problem.

Comment: If the other answers "do not solve the problem", then maybe the problem wasn't stated clearly enough?