# How can I remove space after `\right`?

Tags: spacing, equations

Why is it that after `\right)`, the `.` placed after it is spaced. It looks disturbing.
For example:

`\begin{equation}
\left(x+y=z\right).
\end{equation}`
There exists an automatic slight space between `)` and `.` that I would like to get rid of if possible?
EDIT: 
Here is a better example,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
4x+y-z =& \left( \int_3^7 dr+ \right. \\
    & \left. y+x\mathcal{M} \right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

What has been discussed in the comments, is to define `\usepackage{mleftright}` though without an application, things are still a little difficult to understand.

Comment: One can manually remove math space with `\!`, or if one needs a finer measure, `\mkern-#mu`, where `#` is replaced with a decimal value.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Maybe `\mkern-\nulldelimiterspace` is also useful to you.

Comment: That's because `\left(...\right)` becomes inner atom, which is different from plain `(...)` with respect to spacing around it. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right) for more detail.

Comment: @Merzong I have read the best answer there but I do not seem to understand how it applies. Does he mean that one should define a new command after listing the packages and then insert \mathopen{} and \mathclose{} where necessary? Or without defining he commands, directly use \mathopen{} and \mathclose{}? In either ways, it did not work for me.

Comment: @1010011010 Sorry I do not see where you're going? How and where to place this command?

Comment: If you don't want the spaces that can come before `\left<fence>` and after `\right<fence>`, load the `mleftright` package and use `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right`. Or, if you are certain you never want those spaces, load the `mleftright` package and issue the instruction `\mleftright`: That way, `\left` and `\right` will behave like `\mleft` and `\mright` throughout the document.

Comment: When I use `\left(x+y=z\right)\!.`, the space between the right paren and the subsequent period definitely *does* shrink.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas Just define new `\left` and `\right` in the preamble and use them. It works for me. Another way to correct the spacing is using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` of `mathtools` package.

Comment: @Merzong I did use it then in the right place. If afterwards what you mean that I place `\mright)` and `\mleft(` instead of `\right)` and `\left(` then it does not work for me. If you mean that I keep them as `\left(` and `\right)` then it also does not work. I will edit my question with a better example.

Comment: To load the `mleftright` package, issue the instruction `\usepackage{mleftright}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas - Sorry that my earlier comments weren't clear enough. After loading the `mleftright` package (in the preamble), you should write `\mleft` and `\mright` (in the body of the document) instead of `\left` and `\right` to avoid getting the occasional extra spacing around the fence symbols.

Comment: @Mico does it work also if as in my case, I am breaking the line that begins with an open parenthesis and ends with a closed parathesis? Because in my example, I have `\right.` and `\left.` too. I am sensing that this does not apply in my case, isn't it?

Comment: Sure. Compile this if you can, this is how this should look like after I follow your instructions. @Mico

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
4x+y-z =& \mleft( \int_3^7 dr+ \right. \\
    & \left. y+x\mathcal{M} \mright).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

Comment: @Beyond-formulas - What are you trying to achieve by mixing-and-mismatching `\mleft` with `\right` and `\left` with `\mright`? Either use one type of instructions or the other, but don't mix them up.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work @Mico. I have replaced `\left.` by `\mleft`, `\right.` by `\mright.`, `\left(` by `\mleft(` and `\right)` by `\mright)` as you suggested but with no result :(...

Comment: @Beyond-formulas - I'm afraid "this does not work" is simply not specific enough to draw any inferences. Do you get error and/or warning messages? Are the horizontal spacing issues (which ones, by the way?) not affected by the use of `\mleft` and `\mright`? Is it the *vertical* size of the fences across the two rows that's unsatisfactory? Did the answer Heiko gave to your follow-up posting help at all?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27355/discussion-on-question-by-beyond-formulas-how-can-i-remove-space-after-right).

Answer (score 3):

Your example produces

[image]

Which has extra space as the two `\left\right` pairs make `\mathinner` atoms which typically get `\thinmuskip` space around them (the same space as `\,` which is 1.7pt here) and additional `\nulldelimiterspace` (1.2pt here) from the two invisible delimiters `\right.` on the first line and `\left.` on the second.

However *far* more disturbing than this white space is the mis-matched size of the `()`.

If you use fixed size delimiters all these problems go, the brackets are the same size, and there are no null delimiters or mathinner groups creating unwanted horizontal space.  I also brought the `+` on to the next line. If you do want it at the end of the first line it should be marked up as `+{}` so that it keeps its infix spacing, `aligned` only automatically supports the convention where binary operators start the continuation line as used below.

[image]

(The remaining white space between the `)` and `.` is not white space added by TeX it is white space within the font's glyph for the `)` character.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
4x+y-z =& \Bigl( \int_3^7 dr  \\
    & + y+x\mathcal{M} \Bigr).
\end{aligned}
```

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: See also the manual of the `mathtools` package, end of subsection 3.6.1 (pp. 28–29),