# How to correctly set functions using `\left(` and `\right)`?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

If one uses `\left(` and `\right)` to set functions an extra space is created between the function name and the brackets. How does one correctly set functions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  Compare $f(x)$ and $f\left(x\right)$.
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Because of the duplicate tag that was not removed when I edited my question, I created a new question which has a useful answer here: [How to correctly set functions with `\left(` and `\right)`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309851/how-to-correctly-set-functions-with-left-and-right?noredirect=1#comment752983_309851)

Comment: it is best to avoid `\left\right` certainly in cases like this where you do not want a large bracket at all

Comment: You're answering your own question: `$f(x)$` is the right way.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740 and the duplicate question linked from there

Comment: See [Spacing around left and right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607) and [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173771) and probably other related questions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out the other posts. But I don't see why one should not use `left(` and `right)` in such cases. Think about arguments that have an increased height. And if one has to fix it in that case why not just use that fixed way generally?

Comment: With my new edits I don't see how the other posts directly answer my question. Maybe you can point it out to me or remove the the duplicate mark?

Comment: Okay, I just re-posted the question more clearly, since I really need an answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309851/how-to-correctly-set-functions-with-left-and-right.

Comment: @David Carlisle I am happy to delete this one but someone needs to remove the duplicate status on the other one first because it is locked...