# How to correctly set functions with `\left(` and `\right)`?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

If one uses `\left(` and `\right)` to set functions an extra space is created between the function name and the brackets. How does one correctly set functions?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  Compare \[f(\frac{1}{2})\] and \[f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\].
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Here is a (probably too easy) solution by using a negative space:

```
f\!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
```

Comment: How is this really different from your other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309829/how-to-correctly-set-functions-using-left-and-right, which was closed as duplicate?

Comment: Note if you think the closed question isn't a duplicate, you can edit it and it may be re-opened, please don't just re-ask the same question

Comment: I did for a while. But it wasn't changed. So I opened another question. Notice also that the content is different.

Comment: I did not close the other question as a duplicate and don't agree that it is. The answer to my question here is also evidence that it is not.

Comment: Daniel the answer here could apply to the older questions too I don't see anything different here really?

Comment: David, Agreed. So just remove the duplicate reference in this question to the other question so I can delete the other and all can be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright` avoid the additional space.
Also often a slightly smaller version can be set manually improving the output. In this case, I would reduce the size of the fraction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
  Compare: \[f(\frac{1}{2})\]
  \[f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\]
  \[f\mleft(\frac{1}{2}\mright)\]
  \[f\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\]
  \[f\mleft(\tfrac{1}{2}\mright)\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Yes, I see how the space is better with `\mleft` and `\mright`. It seems still a bit further away.  But I guess that is as good as it get without manually fiddling with the spaces, right?

Comment: @Daniel The larger parentheses also have larger side bearings.

Comment: I see. But it just looks so slight that it should not make such a big difference. Well, I guess anyway, it is the best one gets.