# Different height of symbols in prescript with hat

Tags: accents, left-superscripts

I am trying to use such code:

```
$$ \boldsymbol{f}\left(\prescript{S}{E}{\hat{\boldsymbol{q}}},\prescript{E}{}{\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}}, \prescript{S}{}{\hat{\boldsymbol{s}}}\right) $$
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

as you can see the height of the letters in pre-supscript differs with height of the main letter. Any idea how to align these?

Comment: We need a mini document that we can compile this command with relevant packages or macro definitions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Side note: Don't use `$$....$$` -- that's deprecated. Use `\[...\]`

Comment: you might try adding an empty group `{}` at the beginning of the "hatted" argument if that letter is tall.

Comment: That was a fast response! Sorry about not providing all necessary information and thanks for the help. Using the empty group {} as @barbarabeeton suggested solved the problem :)

Comment: Incidentally, using `\left` here gives the wrong spacing, either use a specifically size bracket, such as `\bigl(` or precede the `\left` with `\mathopen{}` or use a `mathtools` paired delimiter, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/15925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using empty group as suggested in the comments solved it, so the final code is:

`\[ \boldsymbol{f}\left(\prescript{S}{E}{\hat{\boldsymbol{q}}},\prescript{E}{}{}\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}, \prescript{S}{}{\hat{\boldsymbol{s}}}\right) \]`

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

In normal math mode, subscripts and superscripts are placed *ignoring* math accents and the same should be with `\prescript`; unfortunately, `mathtools` doesn't exclude math accents from consideration when deciding the dimensions of the phantom to which the “prescripts” are attached to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\remove@math@accents{%
  \let\hat\@firstofone
  % add the accents you need to cope with
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\xpatchcmd{\MT_prescript_inner:}{{#3}}{{\remove@math@accents#3}}{}{}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\bm{f}(
  \prescript{S}{E}{\hat{\bm{q}}},
  \prescript{E}{}{\hat{\bm{d}}},
  \prescript{S}{}{\hat{\bm{s}}}
)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for great answer, though I'll go with the simple trick for now :)