# Problem with nesting macros

Tags: nesting, ifthenelse

I have written a macro to denote either the Fourier transformation (curly F by itself) or the Fourier transform of a function (curly F followed by a function and enclosed in \left( and \right) ). It does so by testing if the argument is equal to void or not:

```
\newcommand*{\fourier}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathscr{F}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\!\left({#1}\right)}}}%
```

Therefore

```
\fourier{}
```

or

```
\fourier{f(\omega t)}
```

give the expected results.

I wanted to apply \fourier twice to a function and therefore wrote

```
\fourier{\fourier{f}}(x)
```

However, I'm getting a `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` error. How should I modify my macro so that it allows nesting? I'm guessing it's because of the `\ifthenelse` construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon)'s original [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449484/35864), but pretending to be [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and sticking to the mandatory argument. The starred version uses `\left`/`\right`, the unstarred version has an optional parameter for `\big`/`\Big`/...

Taking the approach to `\left` and `\right` from [Mateus Araújo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1035/mateus-ara%c3%bajo)'s answer to [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/35864)  with help from [Philipp Stephani](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/-syt_OhARtA/7-MdMmEfrIcJ) (thanks to [Ruixi Zhang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/164314/ruixi-zhang) for the suggestion in the comments)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fourier}{%
  \mathscr{F}%
  \@ifstar
    \fourier@paren@star
    \fourier@paren@expl}
\newcommand{\fourier@paren@star}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(#1\right)}%
  \fi}
\newcommand{\fourier@paren@expl}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  \else
    \mathopen{#1(}#2\mathclose{#1)}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \fourier{} \]
\[ \fourier{f(\omega t)} \]
\[ \fourier{\fourier{f}}(x) \]
\[ \fourier*{\fourier*{\frac{f^2}{2\pi}}}(x) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That space `\!` before `\left` and `\right` though. Why not use the classic solution by Philipp Stephani: `\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left( #1 \right)}`. For the `\fourier[\big]{...}` variants, I was wondering if there is a possible direct use of `\bigl` and `\bigr`. ;-)

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thanks for the hint. I had copied the `\left` `\right` bit from the OP. I'll see if I can find something that works for `\big`->`\bigl`/`\bigr`, though I'm not sure if that is necessary when we already use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Given that `\bigl` is just `\def\bigl{\mathopen\big}` I don't think the conversion from `\big` to `\bigl` is really necessary here. If anyone is interested I came up with `\newcommand{\frde@size@getlr}[3]{\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1#2\endcsname#3}` which you can use as `\frde@size@getlr{\big}{l}{(}` to get `\bigl(`.

Comment: You are right. Unlike the “simple wrapper” from `mathtools` which does `\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 l} #2` and `\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 r} #3`, going this extra mile to get `\bigl(` just seems convoluted.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your solutions and hints. I did not know much about how `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` could solve my spacing problem, I will definitely be using that.

I did not have much use for the `\big` version although I understand it may be useful. On the other hand I modified the macro (and renamed it as `\integraltransform`) so it would accept a second argument to use as the symbol, as may be useful for example for Laplace transformation : `\newcommand{\laplace}[1]{\integraltransform{\mathscr{L}}{#1}}%` and conjugate Fourier transform (with `\overline{\mathscr{F}}` as the symbol).

Comment: @FrédéricDelacroix Many expert users prefer the explicit size commands over the automatic sizing with `\left`/`\right` because the automatic commands may pick out sizes that are unnecessarily large or too small in certain situations (there is even a quote from the TeXbook that acknowledges that and it is reproduced in an answer here, but I can't find that right now).

Answer (score 10):

I'd use the following:

1. don't use `\ensuremath` it tends to obfuscate source code
2. don't use `\ifthenelse` to check for an empty argument, but `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` (expandable, plus personal preferences)
3. use an optional argument for an optional argument

**I've made a mistake** therefore the former code grabbed the arguments wrong. The following uses `xparse` to grab the arguments in a more robust way. It therefore doesn't use the `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` test but `xparse`'s `\IfValueT`.

Results:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \fourier { o }
  {%
    \mathscr{F}\IfValueT{#1}{\!\left(#1\right)}%
  }%

\begin{document}
$\fourier[\fourier[f]](x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]