# Superfluous space with mtpro2 after making \left/\right into \mathopen/\mathclose

Tags: spacing, delimiters, mtpro

### This question adds another reason why one shouldn’t abuse the `\left` and `\right` pair

Automatic delimiter sizing through a `\left` and `\right` pair should *always* be avoided, with *few* exceptions (e.g., cases, matrices, etc.). In fact, pages 146 – 149 of *The TeXbook* showcase many examples where manual sizing is used. Using `\left` and `\right` in those examples would no doubt produce sub-optimal or even ugly output.

There is also the problem of spacing: A `\left` and `\right` pair effectively creates a `\mathinner` object, which follows different spacing rules (e.g., `$\sin(x)$` versus `$\sin\left(x\right)$`). However, even after one has made `\left<delimiter>...\right<delimiter>` to behave like `\mathopen<delimiter>...\mathclose<delimiter>`, there *still* are potential problems.

### The current problem

I have used [this technique](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/-syt_OhARtA/7-MdMmEfrIcJ) from Philipp Stephani mentioned in this post: [Spacing around `\left` and `\right`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/164314). For strange reasons, there is still superfluous space between certain letters and the opening delimiter.

**Note**: The following MWE is of no practical use by its own. However, I think it serves as one of many reasons why one shouldn’t abuse `\left` and `\right`, even after they are “fixed”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&f\left(x\right) \quad                  &&\vert\left(x\right) \\
&f\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(x\right)} &&\vert\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(x\right)} \\
&f(x)                                   &&\vert(x)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image: superfluous space]

Why is there superfluous space, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

$f(x)$

$f\mathopen{}\mathclose{(x)}$

$f\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left(x\right)}$

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The output for the first formula is

```
....\mathon
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 f
....\kern2.4
....\kern-0.8
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 .
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 x
....\kern0.5
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 /
....\mathoff
```

For the second formula it is

```
....\mathon
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 f
....\kern2.4
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(7.17+2.13998)x13.42998
.....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 .
.....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 x
.....\kern0.5
.....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 /
....\mathoff
```

For the final one it is

```
....\mathon
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 f
....\kern2.4
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(7.17497+2.13501)x13.42998
.....\hbox(7.17497+2.13501)x13.42998
......\hbox(7.17+2.13998)x3.73, shifted -0.00497
.......\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 .
......\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 x
......\kern0.5
......\hbox(7.17+2.13998)x3.73, shifted -0.00497
.......\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 /
....\mathoff
```

What's the difference? Just a `\kern-0.8`.

By rule, TeX adds the italic correction after `f` (`\kern2.4`); in the first formula the `f` is followed by a left parenthesis (which is at the slot for `.` in the math symbol font of `mtpro2`) and a kerning is defined for this pair, exactly `\kern-0.8`.

In the second and third formula the kerning cannot be applied.

I add the picture from the code above for the few people who can't see it from the symbolic representations above. It can be seen that the positioning of `(` and `x` is the same, but in the second and third rows the parenthesis is a bit to the right with respect to the first one (by the precise amount of 0.8pt, the missing kern).

[image]

With `\vert` the problem doesn't show, because no kerning is defined between `|` and `(`.

Just for checking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{$f(x)$} % define the math fonts

{\the\textfont1 f.}
{\the\textfont1 f\/}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

We get (reduced)

```
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 f
....\kern-0.8
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 .

....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/10 f
....\kern 2.4
```

Can you do better? Yes, not using `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: +1 for "not using `\left` and `\right`". :-)

Comment: Could you please clarify which output belongs to which formula? There are 3 outputs but only 2 formulae.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Oh, sorry, I forgot to add one in the middle. Fixed.

Comment: Your formulas are not in same order as image in OP, so it would be nice to get an image here too matching the order as in your answer.

Comment: @jfbu They are different on purpose: I'm comparing `$f(x)$`, `$f\mathopen{}\mathclose{(x)}$` and `$f\mathopen{}{\mathclose{\left(x\right)}$`, in order to show that the culprit is `\mathopen{}`.

Comment: no pity for the visual type persons who only understand via images? hmm... I wonder if the didactic committee properly examined your records as professor!

Comment: @jfbu It was pretty difficult to show pictures of rings and modules and the committee agreed. `;-)` But I added the image for those few people who can't figure out the output from the symbolic representation of “boxes and glue”. `;-)`

Comment: some people like to fancy `spec Z` as 3-dimensional but the real difficulty comes with the geometry over the field with 1 element `;-)`