# Should \left and \right almost be used for brackets?

Tags: formatting

Apart from automatically setting the size for brackets, the commands `\left` and `\right` also adds spacing around the corresponding brackets. The spacing in which one uses both `\left(` and `\right)` and parentheses without these commands  the spacing might therefor be inconsistent. Is the intention behind this that the commands `\left` and `right` should always be used when parentheses are inserted into equations?

If not, what is good practice for when to use these?

Comment: No, they shouldn't be used indiscriminately.

Comment: You might find some insight in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607). I'm sure there are others, but I can't find them at the moment.

Comment: Anyhow, use `\left` and `\right` when `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` aren't big enough. In this case, the whole expression is probably so large that the extra spaces added by `\left` and `right` are desirable. (Or you can look in the latex2e source code and make your own `\biggger` macros.)