# Increase spacing between custom \left and \prod & \sum

Tags: spacing, brackets

I slightly modified the spacing around `\left` and `\right` [as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610).

```
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}
```

I like the look of the modified versions better in every case except when immediately followed by `\prod` or `\sum`. In that case, the spacing is too tight as shown below.

**Regular left**

[image: regular left]

**Custom left**

[image: custom left]

**Code**

```
\vec z_k \sim p_k(\vec z_k) = p_0(\vec z_0) \ \prod_{i=1}^k
\left|
  \det \frac{\partial f_i(\vec z_{i-1})}{\partial \vec z_{i-1}}
\right|^{-1}.
```

**Q**: Is there a way to go back to the old spacing in only that case and keep the changes to `\left` and `\right` everywhere else?

Answer (score 5):

The link you've found is quite old. The issue discussed in that link has [given rise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145341/5001) to the [mleftright](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package, which provides macros called `\mleft` and `\mright`. In short, no need anymore to modify `\left` and `\right` by hand.

I would either load the `mleftright` package and use `\mleft\vert` and `\mright\vert` or load the `mathtools` package and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to create a macro called `\abs` (and, automatically, the variant macro `\abs*` which auto-sizes the "fences"). As the first two lines in the following screenshot demonstrate, both methods produce the same, i.e., tight-looking output.

Finally, to address your question directly: If you prefer the look produced by `\mleft{<fence>}` and `\mright{<fence>}` in most use cases, you could issue the instruction `\mleftright` at the top of the document; this makes `\left` and `\right` behave like `\mleft` and `\mright` by default. If you need to revert to the "standard" behavior of `\left` and `\right`, simply issue the command `\mleftrightrestore`; this also works locally, i.e., in a TeX group. E.g., something like this: `\begingroup \mleftrightrestore \left\vert <stuff> \right\vert \endgroup`. See also the third line of the screenshot and its associated LaTeX code. Alternatively, if for some reason you prefer *not* to employ the `mleftright` package and, instead, wish to use the code you posted in your query to modify the default properties of `\left` and `\right`, simply use `\originalleft` and `\originalright` to access the original [pun intended] workings of `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter utility macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\vert}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright % make \mleft and \mright the default

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vec z_k \sim p_k(\vec z_k) 
&= p_0(\vec z_0) \prod_{i=1}^k
  \abs*{ 
    \det \frac{\partial f_i(\vec{z}_{i-1})}{\partial\vec{z}_{i-1}}
  }^{-1} \\
&= p_0(\vec z_0) \prod_{i=1}^k
  \left\vert % remember that behavior of \left and \right has been changed
    \det \frac{\partial f_i(\vec{z}_{i-1})}{\partial\vec{z}_{i-1}}
  \right\vert^{-1}\\
&= p_0(\vec z_0) \prod_{i=1}^k
  \begingroup \mleftrightrestore % restore behavior of \left and \right locally
  \left\vert 
    \det \frac{\partial f_i(\vec{z}_{i-1})}{\partial\vec{z}_{i-1}}
  \right\vert^{-1} \endgroup
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```