# Restoring missing space before large parentheses in `newtxmath`?

Tags: mathtools, newtxmath

As shown by the difference between the two lines of the image below, for sufficiently large pairs of parentheses in `newtxmath`, the space in front of the left parenthesis disappears. This results in spacing that is more cramped than desired. Is there a clean (i.e., without manually adjusting the kerning each time) way to restore this space?

[image]

Here is the code used to generate that image:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{\lparen}{\rparen}
\newcommand*{\tall}{\int_0^{t^2} x\,dx}
\newcommand*{\taller}{\sum_{\substack{(k,m)=1\\0 < k < m}} k}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\exp\paren*{\tall} \\
  &\exp\paren*{\taller}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don’t use the `minimal` class. It’s not meant for examples.

Answer (score 2):

I prepared two `standalone` documents, doing `\fbox{\Bigg(}` first with Computer Modern, then with `newtxmath`, setting `\fboxsep` to 0pt and `\fboxrule` to 0.1pt in order to precisely show the bounding box.

The command `\Bigg` works exactly the same in text as in math. Next, I did `\includegraphics` with both outputs, getting

[image]

(left CM, right NewTX).

Next experiment, I typeset `$\exp\paren[\Bigg]{}$` in both standalone documents.

[image]

You can note that the difference in the bounding boxes has an important role.

The difference in the bounding boxes is even more outstanding for really bigger parentheses. Here's the experiment: I define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Bigggg}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\makeatother
```

and retry the first experiment, getting

[image]

Again, left is Computer Modern, right is NewTX. The size is slightly smaller in the latter case, but this shows the problem is in how the bounding box of the composed parentheses are defined.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `\left` and `\right`, [TeX inserts additional spacing around the delimiters.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right)  A command declared with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` does not.  Therefore, if you wanted the extra space after an operator, you could switch to `\left(` and `\right)`.

You could also define a command that expands to `\,\paren{#1}` and use that.

I know I say this a lot, but this is another one of the many, many problems that goes away if you switch to the modern toolchain. `unicode-math` with TeX Gyre Termes Math looks very similar to `newtxmath`, but does not have this bug.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, this issue is unrelated to `\mathopen{}` and `\mathclose{}`: Both the first and second line use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, yet there is a difference in spacing for the larger pair of parentheses.

Comment: @cubesteak Right, but switching will still get you the additional space you wanted.

Comment: If I switch both sets of parentheses to `\left(` and `\right)`, the inconsistency in spacing persists. (Of course, I could only use `\left(` and `\right)` for sufficiently large parentheses, but this would be no better than manually inserting a `mkern` when needed.)

Comment: @cubesteak Another fix is to change fonts to one with better spacing around its extensible symbols?

Comment: Yes---that certainly would work :) I quite like the `newtxmath` font, so I was just curious if this issue could be fixed without switching fonts entirely.

Comment: @cubesteak Maybe insert a `\mathop` atom before the left delimiter?

Comment: Manually adding space like that does work (I find that `\mkern1.5mu` looks good).

To add this space automatically, do you happen to know if it's possible to obtain the "size" of parentheses scaled using `\left` and `\right`, e.g., the number of extensible segments used?

Comment: @cubesteak First idea that comes to mind is to store the inner expression in a box, measure its height, and compare that to a threshold value?

Comment: Thanks! Will give that a shot.

Comment: @cubesteak This problem also goes away if you use TeX Gyre Termes Math with `unicode-math`. It’s very similar to `newtxmath`.