# What is `\mathopen{}` for?

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, mathtools

On `mathtools` manual, page 27, there is an example defining a command `\Set`:

```
% just to make sure it exists
\providecommand\given{}
% can be useful to refer to this outside \Set
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:#1\vert
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
    \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
    #1
}
```

What is this `\mathopen{}` for? I read the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right/), which involves  `\mathopen` along with some explanations, but still don't understand it here.

---

**Edit:**

I just saw that on page 26 in a previous example there is some explanation:

[image]

[image]

Does this mean that `\mathopen{}` here is basically the same as `\mathopen\delimsize\vert` (I'm not sure if this is a valid combination)?

Comment: (I was about to say "the command is documented in <book>" before realizing the question asks for "why is this command useful in this particular command". -- assuming you already know about character classes and the spacing inserted between them?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people write `]-1,1[` to denote the *open* interval from `-1` to `1`. The default TeX math status of the characters `[` and `]` is `mathopen` and `mathclose`, respectively. To properly typeset the open interval mentioned in the first sentence, it's a really good idea to input it as

```
\mathopen{]} -1 , 1 \mathclose{[}
```

---

[image]

Observe that if one fails to inform TeX that the `]` character should be treated as having type `mathopen`, TeX is led to interpret the `-` ("minus") character as a binary instead of as a unary operator.

---

The term `\mathopen{}` inserts an empty atom of type `mathopen` into the input stream. This is helpful in case the material that comes *after* `\vert` starts with a unary operator such as `+`, `-`, `\pm`, etc. (The default math status of `\vert` is `mathord`.)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$]-1,1[$ \qquad $\mathopen{]}-1,1\mathclose{[}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is good to know. In France people tend to use the notation `]-1,1[` instead of `(-1,1)`. But this doesn't seem to answer the original question.

Comment: Jinwen - Thanks. I've added a paragraph to discuss the purpose of `\mathopen{}`.