# Unwanted spacing right before \left (

Tags: amsmath

When I run the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathbb{E} [x]\\
  \mathbb{E} \left[x\right]\\
  \mathbb{E} {\left[x\right]}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

where I have an unwanted space right before `\left`. Is this a flaw of `\left` and `\right`?
Can I redefine them as follow?

```
\let\oldleft\left
\let\oldright\right
\def\left#1{\bgroup\oldleft#1}
\def\right#1{\oldright#1\egroup}
```

I think the answer is no though.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/ is perhaps of interest.

Comment: also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740/1090

Comment: there is no reason to use leftright here at all. But in general see mleftright package or `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from mathtools